# Problems with the brightness of the photo taken (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: java, android, xamarin.android

I'm creating an app in Xamarin Android. The UI is a single button, by clicking on which a photo is taken, but without the appearance of previews. Сode for taking photos and camera settings:

```
 private void TakePhotoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        camera = Open();
        try
        {
            camera.SetPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(10));
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            //Log.e(Version.APP_ID, e1.getMessage());
        }

        Parameters newParameters = GetModifiedCameraParameters();
        camera.SetParameters(newParameters);
        camera.StartPreview();
        camera.TakePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback());
    }

    private Parameters GetModifiedCameraParameters()
    {
        Parameters parameters = camera.GetParameters();
        Size size = FindMaxSize(parameters.SupportedPictureSizes);

        parameters.SetPreviewSize(640, 480);
        parameters.SetPictureSize(size.Width, size.Height);
        parameters.Set("contrast", "0");
        parameters.FlashMode = Parameters.FlashModeOff;
        parameters.FocusMode = Parameters.FocusModeAuto;
        parameters.SceneMode = Parameters.SceneModeAuto;
        parameters.AutoExposureLock = false;
        parameters.WhiteBalance = Parameters.WhiteBalanceAuto;
        parameters.ExposureCompensation = 12;
        parameters.PictureFormat = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
        parameters.JpegQuality = 100;
        parameters.SetRotation(90);    

        return parameters;
    }

    private Size FindMaxSize(IList<Size> sizes)
    {
            Size[] orderByDescending = sizes
                                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Width)
                                    .ToArray();
            return orderByDescending[0];
    }
```

The result is a photo of good quality, but low brightness. I tried changing the exposure, ISO. Really increased the brightness of the photo contrast change. But the photo is still not bright enough. The manifest file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.workwithcamera" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method in Camera parameters to set the brightness, you could use Media Plugin.

The sample is for xamarin.forms android.
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

You could increase the brightness manully.

[image]